# Example for a two norms and vector space which are equivalent on this Vectorspace

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I need an example where the [image]

two norms and the vector space are equivalent on the vector space.

Comment: how can be norm equivalent to vector space?

Comment: you can check from there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Comment: Norms $||.||_1,||.||_2,||.||_\inf$ are equivalent in $R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for item c) you must prove the following result:

Theorem: Let E be a vector space of finite dimension. Then all norms on E are equivalent.

Thus, the example of Emin solves the item c) in case $R^n$.

For item d), you should seek norms in spaces of infinite dimension.

Regards